# Redis / Dictionaries / sqlite3 on millions of pairs

Tags: python, database, dictionary, redis

I have pairs (key,value) which consist key = string , value = int. I try to build an index from a large text corpus, so I store the string and an identifier. For every term I read from the corpus I have to check to the index to see if it exists, so I need fast lookups(O(1) if possible). I was using python dictionary to create the index. Problem is that I go out of Ram (16GB Ram). My alternative was to use dictionary and when my ram goes 90% usage I was using a sqlite3 database to store the pairs to the disk. But now the problem is that the seeking time takes too much time(first check dict, if fail go and check database at disk) .

I am thinking to switch to Redis-db. My question is, should I strore the key values as strings or should I hash them and then store them ? (keys are strings which contain (2~100 chars). And what about the values, should I try anything on them (values are int32 numbers)?

edit:

I want to store every term and its identifier(unique pairs) , and if i read a term and it exists inside the index then pass it.

edit2:

I tried using redis but it seems it goes really slow (?) , I use the same code instead of dictionary I use redis set & get which are supposed to have O(1) complexity, but the building time of the index is tooo slow. any advice ?

Comment: If your use case can tolerate a small percentage of false positives (ie. a key is determined to exist but it doesn't in actuality) then you could take a look at using a [bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter)

Answer (score 0):

A Python dictionary can be simulated with C hashes quite easely. Glib provides a working hash implementation that is not difficult to use with some C training. The advantage is that is will be faster and (much) less memory hungry that the Python dictionary:

https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.40/glib-Hash-Tables.html

[GLib Hash Table Loop Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700485/glib-hash-table-loop-problem)

You can also add some algorithm to improve the performance. For example store a compressed key.

Even easier, you can segment your large text corpus in sections, create an independent index for each section and then "merge" the indexes.

So for example index 1 will look:

```
key1 -> page 1, 3, 20
key2 -> page 2, 7
...
```

index 2:

```
key1 -> page 50, 70
key2 -> page 65
...
```

Then you can merge index 1 and 2:

```
key1 -> page 1, 3, 20, 50, 70
key2 -> page 2, 7, 65
...
```

You can even paralelize into N machines.

Comment: Sorry i didn't say that I store unique pairs, your approach is based on chains. I want to store every term and its identifier , and if i read a term and it exists inside the index then pass it.

Answer (score 0):

> should I store the key values as strings or should I hash them and then store them? [...] what about the values?

The most naive way to use Redis in your case is to perform a [`SET`](http://redis.io/commands/set) for every unique pair, e.g `SET foo 1234` and so on.

As demonstrated by Instagram (x) what you can do instead is using Redis Hashes that feature transparent memory optimizations behind the scenes:

> Hashes [...] when
>   smaller than a given number of elements, and up to a maximum element
>   size, are encoded in a very memory efficient way that uses up to 10
>   times less memory

(see Redis [memory optimization](http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization) documentation for more details).

As suggested by Instagram what you can do is:

1. hash every key with a 64-bit hash function: `n = hash(key)`
2. compute the corresponding bucket: `b = n/1000` (with 1,000 elements per bucket)
3. store the hash, value (= `i`) pair in this bucket: `HSET b n i`

*Note: keep your integer value `i` as-is since behind the scenes integers are encoded using a variable number of bytes in ziplists.*

Of course make sure to configure Redis with `hash-max-ziplist-entries 1000` to make sure every hash will be memory optimized (xx).

To speed up your initial insertion, you may want to use the raw Redis protocol via [mass insertion](http://redis.io/topics/mass-insert).

(x) [Storing hundreds of millions of simple key-value pairs in Redis](http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/12202313862/storing-hundreds-of-millions-of-simple-key-value-pairs).

**Edit**:

(xx) even though in practice most (**if not all**) of your hashes will contain a single element because of the sparsity of the hash function. In other words, since your keys are hashed strings and not monotonically increasing ID-s as in Instagram exemple, this approach may **NOT** be as interesting in terms of memory saving (all your ziplists will contain a single pair). You may want to load your dataset and see what it does with real data in comparison to the basic `SET key(= string) value(= integer)` approach.